# Can't get MediaStore.Images.Media after reboot

Tags: java, android, image, mediastore

I developed an app which saves photos inside the app folder (/android/data/[app-folder]/files/Report/[directory]) with some data saved into DESCRIPTION field, here is my code to save image:

```
ContentValues image = new ContentValues();
image.put(Images.Media.TITLE, directory);
image.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, FOTOC_PREFIX_NAME + "_" + directory + "_" + data + ".jpg");
image.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "EXAMPLE DESC");
image.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
image.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
image.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, 0);
File parent = imagePath.getParentFile();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
 image.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, parent.getAbsolutePath());
}
image.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, parent.toString().toLowerCase().hashCode());
image.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, parent.getName().toLowerCase());
image.put(Images.Media.SIZE, imagePath.length());
image.put(Images.Media.DATA, imagePath.getAbsolutePath());
Uri result = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY), image);
```

And then i read data with:

```
String whereCause = MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '%" + UsefullThings.getNameWithoutExtension(photofile.getName()) + "%'";
String[] projection = new String[] {MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media
                                                            .getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY), projection, whereCause, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
 if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
   cursor.moveToFirst();
 }

 String descstring = "";
 try {
  descstring =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION));
 }catch(Exception e){
  ....
 }
```

where photofile is the image.
Everything is working fine, but if i reboot my tablet then the same query returns empty cursor.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: `the same query returns empty cursor.` Ok. But what does that have to do wit a description field? Confusing post.

Comment: Further you did not tell where the file lands and if the file is still there after reboot. You could also save the uri  result.toString() to shared preferences and use it after reboot. Please examine if the uri is still valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > app which saves photos inside the app folder (/android/data/[app-folder]/files/Report/[directory])

You mean /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[app-folder]/files/Report/[directory] ?

That is impossible to begin with if you use the MediaStore.

That is an app specific directory and the MediaStore will not give you insert() uries for that location.

> > image.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, parent.getAbsolutePath());

You should put a relative path in .RELATIVE_PATH. Not a full absolute path as you do now. Also we cannot see what exactly you put in there. Please tell value of parent.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: Thanks for reply, but if it is impossible, why it works until i reboot the tablet?

Comment: The code works. Ok. But I asked you if the file is created in that app specific directory. AND if it is still there after reboot. But you do seem it not necessary to answer that question. Also please tell Android version of used device.

Comment: Sorry, i'm using android 11, the file was created in that specific directory correctly and yes the file is still there after reboot.

Comment: That is hard to believe as it would be a backdoor. I will check soon. By the way: how did you check that the file was there? As file managers on Android 11 have no access to app specific directories.

Comment: i found a workaround saving the description data into separated text file instead of using MediaStore API, thank for help

Comment: You could have answered my questions first before thanking. Now i still know nothing.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice that you updated your comment before i posted mine, however the tablet is connected to my PC so i can browse  all file and directory, plus i have an activity that returns a list of all the files in the app specific directories